# Why do we use "/" to mark the end of a MySQL query?

Tags: oracle

```
create type emp_t AS OBJECT(
    EMPNO CHAR(6),
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(12),
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(15),
    WORKDEPT REF dept_t,
    SEX CHAR(1),
    BIRTHDAY DATE,
    SALARY NUMBER(8,2)
)
/ <--------- this one
```

Comment: The forward slash appears to be a _delimiter_.

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: Provide complete batch text, not only one query from it.

Comment: Are you sure that this is MySQL?

Comment: yes this oracle command

Comment: Um.. no.. although MySQL is currently developed by Oracle, it is not similar to Oracle's own db. Wiki Oracle and look at their "Database" topic/section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment said, that is used as a Delimiter, but it has to be assigned first.
The normal delimiter is `(;)`, you can set a new one by adding the command and then the sign you want to use.

Once change the delimiter, you can use the new delimiter to end a statement as follows:

```
DELIMITER //

SELECT * FROM customers //

SELECT * FROM products //
```

Here is some [Documentation.](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-delimiter/)

Comment: thank you for your answer and I appreciate it